# how to place tableau reports in .net web form application

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, tableau-api

In C# 2010/2012 .net web form applications, I know that ssrs reports can be accessed in the application using a reportviewer control. However now my company is going to be using tableau. Thus I am wondering if tableau can be accessed by a .net application? If so, can you tell me how to access the tableau reports? Can you tell me how to accomplish this goal and/or point me to a url that will explain how to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your company publishes its visualizations to either your own Tableau Server or to (SAaS) Tableau OnLine Server, then the visualizations will be available via a URL.

See the Tableau Server Admin manual section on [embedded views](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/embed_landing.htm) to start to learn about your alternatives. It should allow you to embed a view in any web page, and interact via the JavaScript API if desired. If your .Net forms application can display HTML content via some component, then you should be able to display Tableau as with any other HTML content.

You might run into fewer edge cases in the long run if you use HTML5/CSS3/JavaScript apps for end user interaction and save .Net for crunching data. That is closer to the expected usage model, but I've certainly seen .Net clients devote part of their UI to HTML content.

There are other alternatives - such as having your .Net client request reports from Tableau Server in static formats like png, pdf or csv using HTTP directly and then your client can display them as desired. Not usually the best approach because you lose the interactivity that Tableau provides, but can be helpful in some circumstances.

Comment: The embedded views like has rotted away.

Comment: @kenny, thanks for mentioning. I updated the link in the answer

Answer (score 0):

First, Tableau is a data visualization tool. It should be used as an end (showing reports and dashboards), not a mean (e.g., generate standard reports so you can later on get the data and manipulate it yourself).

I don't know what is your goal (please explain if you want a more specific answer), but my short answer would be: Learn how to use Tableau Desktop, it's not hard at all. Using my first point as support, you should be able to do everything you need using Tableau. If not, you should probably work in your data sources directly (to provide data in a format Tableau can do what you need)

Nevertheless, I'm quite convinced (though not 100% sure) that there's a way to access Tableau reports that is not via Tableau Desktop or using a web browser (if report is publish using Tableau Server).

A Javascript API has been recently (a few months ago) launched, I didn't studied it deeply. I know it's possible to interact with reports and dashboards via js, so perhaps it's possible to retrieve data from those reports (I'm guessing that's what you want to do) in a convenient format.